# Spring Integration transaction for subflow of router

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a channel named "creationChannel" which is backed up with MongoMessageStore like this:

```
  @Bean
  ChannelMessageStore messageStore() {
    return new MongoDbChannelMessageStore(mongoDatabaseFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  PollableChannel creationChannel(ChannelMessageStore messageStore) {
    return MessageChannels.queue("creationChannel", messageStore, "create").get();
  }
```

And I want to use it in my flow here, but I want to be sure, that message from there will be read-only if "createOrderHandler" worked fine (the same applies to "updateOrderHandler", but with the different channel).

```
...some code here...
        .<HeadersElement, OperationType>route(
            payload -> route(payload),
            spec -> spec
                .transactional(transactionHandleMessageAdvice)
                .subFlowMapping(
                    OperationType.New,
                    sf -> sf
                        .channel("creationChannel")
                        .log(Level.DEBUG, "Creation of a new order", Message::getPayload)
                        .transform(Mapper::mapCreate)
                        .handle(createOrderHandler,
                            handlerSpec -> handlerSpec.advice(retryOperationsInterceptor))
                )
                .subFlowMapping(
                    OperationType.Update,
                    sf -> sf
                        .channel("updateChannel")
                        .log(Level.DEBUG, "Update for existing order", Message::getPayload)
                        .transform(Mapper::mapUpdate)
                        .handle(updateOrderHandler,
                            handlerSpec -> handlerSpec.advice(retryOperationsInterceptor))
                )
        )
...some code here...
```

I tried to configure "transactionHandleMessageAdvice" like this:

```
  @Bean
  TransactionHandleMessageAdvice transactionHandleMessageAdvice(MongoTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new TransactionHandleMessageAdvice(transactionManager, new Properties());
  }
```

But messages are still being deleted from the database after the handler fails with an exception.

Maybe I should configure Poller for subflows and configure it with MongoTransactionManager somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I should configure Poller for subflows and configure it with MongoTransactionManager somehow?

That's correct assumption. As fast as you have a thread shifting in the flow (like yours `PollableChannel creationChannel`), the current transaction is committed at the moment the message is placed into the store. Nothing more happens in the current thread and, therefore, current transaction which you have started with that `.transactional(transactionHandleMessageAdvice)`.

To make reading transactional, you indeed have to configure a `Poller` on the `.transform(Mapper::mapCreate)` endpoint. So, every poll from that queue channel is going to be transactional until you shift to different thread again.

There is just no way (and must not be) to have the whole async flow transactional since transactions are tied to the `ThreadLocal` and at the moment when call stack comes back to the transaction initiator, it is committed or rolled back. With an async logic we just intend to "send-and-forget" from the producer side and let consumer to deal with data whenever it is ready. That is not what transactions have been designed for.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so you mean that everything after
.channel("creationChannel")
will be executed in a separate thread, and what is the proper way to configure transformation? like this:
                        .transform(Mapper::mapCreate, conf -> conf
                            .transactional(transactionHandleMessageAdvice))
and delete transactionHandleMessageAdvice it from router spec? will log endpoint be a problem if it will stay between channel and transformation?

Comment: The `log()` operator is not an *endpoint* -  it is an *interceptor*: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log. You need to add transactional into a `PollerSpec` of that `transform()` endpoint. Right now I believe you have somewhere a global poller definition which let your flow to work. But if you want to have that polling transactional, you need to be more specific on the endpoint you poll messages via.